# Material-UI XGrid - How to prevent Delete keys to delete cell content

Tags: reactjs, datatable, material-ui

Does anybody know how to prevent the delete key to empty the cell content on the react Material-UI Grid?

Today when you click on a cell and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> it deletes its content. I'd like to prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGrid` will set the cell data to an [empty string](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/blob/d16b250870c353fc70c37c7483b345a2a2d4cebb/packages/grid/_modules_/grid/hooks/features/rows/useGridEditRows.ts#L285) if you hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> while not in edit mode. If you don't like that behavior, you can disable it by attaching a `keydown` handler in the parent element in [capture phase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/9449426) and call `stopPropagation()`:

```js
<div
  onKeyDownCapture={(e) => {
    if (e.key === "Backspace" || e.key === "Delete") {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }}
  style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}
>
  <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
</div>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67067211/metrial-ui-xgrid-how-to-prevent-delete-key-to-delete-cell-content]

Comment: Awesome, I tried the same thing but using onKeyDown instead of onKeyDownCapture but it didn't work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HelioBentes I forgot to clarify that it should work for `XGrid` too because `DataGrid` and `XGrid` share the same internal components but `DataGrid` has some features disabled for free-tier users.